# Confuse for using get queryset and using pass to ignore an exception and proceed in my django view

Tags: python, django, exception, django-queryset

I wrote a view to update my draft object , before updating my draft I need to see if any draft exists for package(draft.package) in db or not .
If any draft available, i need to update that draft's fields.

I am using `get` queryset to look into db to check draft availability.
I want to know that using `get` queryset here is good way or not and using `pass` into `except`.

## My View

```
def save_draft(draft, document_list):
    """    
    """    
    try:
        draft = Draft.objects.get(package=draft.package)
    except Draft.DoesNotExist as exc:
        pass
    except Draft.MultipleObjectsReturned as exc:
        raise CustomException
    else:
        draft.draft_document_list.filter().delete()

    draft.draft_document_list.add(*document_list)
    draft.save()
```

## Extra Information  :

## models.py

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # -- fields

class Document(models.Model):
    # -- fields
   
Class Draft(models.Model):
    # --- fields
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
    draft_document_list = models.ManyToManyField(Document)
```

## My Algorithm :

```
  # first check to see if draft exists for package
  # if exists
      # overwrite draft_document_list with existed draft and save
  # if none exists
      # update passed draft object with draft_document_list
```

## Input variables

```
save_draft(draft, document_list)
draft --> latest draft object
document_list --> list of documents mapped with Draft as M2M.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for for you models and method signature you use `get` right.  To simplify things you can get rid of `delete()`/`add()` methods by direct assign `document_list` to M2M relation.

```
def save_draft(draft, document_list):
    try:
        draft = Draft.objects.get(package=draft.package)
    except Draft.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except Draft.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        raise CustomException
    draft.draft_document_list = document_list
    draft.save()
```

**EDIT**: If there can be only one draft per package then why you use `ForeignKey(Package)`?  With `OneToOne` relation your code will be much simpler:

```
def save_draft(draft, document_list):
    draft.draft_document_list = document_list
    draft.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining direct assigning document_list to M2M relation.In next version of my app one package can have more than one draft that's why i do not want to make it OneToOne.